# How to preload my .so every time an application executes?

Tags: linux, shell-script, process, hook, espeak

I've successfully used a hook under Linux with this article: http://hackerboss.com/overriding-system-functions-for-fun-and-profit/

Now I want to make my .so file load every time `espeak` loads up, no matter if it's called from another application.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could move the `espeak` binary to something like `espeak-real`, and replace it with a small script that sets `LD_PRELOAD` before `exec`'ing `espeak-real`.

```
#! /bin/bash
export LD_PRELOAD=/your/lib.so
exec espeak-real "$@"
```

(stdin/out/err redirections take care of themselves.)

Comment: Can you please give me example, cause I'm not good with `exec`.

Comment: `exec espeak-real`. Couldn't be simpler. Unless you need to pass command line arguments?

Comment: I'll need to, yes. Even some streaming stdin.

Comment: Edited with an example.

Comment: Thank you. Will it work as same as executable if I replace it? (I'm new to unix)

Comment: Essentially yes. Don't forget to make your script executable. You shouldn't accept an answer before you've tested that it works (and given your comment, I don't think you have).